# Editar objeto armazenado em um ArrayList

Tags: java

Tenho a classe `Contato`:

```
public class Contato {
    private String nome;
    private String email;
    private int telefone;
    /*getters e setter*/
}
```

E a classe `Agenda` que tem um `ArrayList` chamado "contatos" onde terei que armazenar os contatos:

```
public class Agenda implements Interface {
    public static ArrayList<Contato> contatos = new ArrayList<Contato>();

    @Override
    public void adicionar(Contato contato) {
        this.contatos.add(contato);     
    }

    @Override
    public void editar(Contato contato) {

    }

    @Override
    public void remover(Contato contato) {
        this.contatos.remove(contato);      
    }

    @Override
    public void buscar(int contato) {

    }
}
```

Até aí tudo bem, então na classe `Agenda` eu tenho os métodos para armazenar os objetos criados na classe `Contato`, consigo adicionar e remover os registros, porém, não sei como fazer o método "editar" (que seria para trazer o objeto, editá-lo e armazenar de volta) e o método buscar (que seria para trazer e mostrar o objeto). Alguma dica?

Comment: O seu método `buscar` recebe um `int`. O que este `int` é para a classe `Contato`? É o telefone do contato, a posição no `ArrayList` ou outra coisa? Para o método `editar` funcionar, também é necessário saber isso antes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve incluir o método `equals` e `hashCode`, os sobreescrevendo na sua classe `Contato`:

```
public class Contato {
        private String nome;
        private String email;
        private int telefone;
        /*getters e setters*/           
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + getOuterType().hashCode();
            result = prime * result + telefone;
            return result;
        }
        @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Contato other = (Contato) obj;
        if (telefone != other.telefone)
            return false;
        return true;
    }


    }
```

**Por que??**

Assim, seus métodos editar e buscar se tornarão extremamente mais simples, pois ArrayList implementa metodos que permitem a você encontrar em uma colecão, o objeto de maneira muito melhor.

**Método editar**

```
        @Override
        public void editar(Contato contato) {
            if(contato == null){
throw new IllegalArgumentException("contato nao pode ser nulo");
            }
            int index = contatos.indexOf(contato);
            if(index > -1){
                contatos.add(index, contato);
            }
        }
```

Por que sua classe Contato agora implementa o método equals podemos rápidamente encontrar o indíce e simplesmente substituir no ArrayList. Existe um problema aqui que oe fato de um ArrayList permitir itens duplicados, mas chagaremos lá.

**Método buscar:**

```
@Override
        public Contato buscar(int contato) {
             List<Contato> contatosAchados = contatos
             .stream()
             .filter(c -> c.telefone == contato)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
             if(!contatosAchados.isEmpty()){
                 return contatosAchados.get(0);
             }
             return null;
        }
```

E no caso de contatos duplicados no ArrayList?

Pois é, o ArrayList, permite elementos duplicados, neste caso, contatos para private e no método adicionar faca uma chamada para o método `contains` verificando se o contato já existe, se já existir, você não adiciona, se não existir ai sim, você o adiciona:

```
@Override
public void adicionar(Contato contato) {
            if(!contatos.contains(contato))
                this.contatos.add(contato);
        }
```

Novamente, o método `equals` permite que você possa usar o contains para verificar se o mesmo já existe.

**Considerações finais**

Considere não referênciar uma Collection por sua implementação concreta e sim por sua interface, ou seja, ao invés de

```
ArraList<Contato> contatos;
```

Utilize:

```
List<Contato> contatos = new ArrayList<>();
```

**O Atributo contatos realmente deve ser público?**

Não sei o que você está fazendo, mas recomendo que não permita que qualquer classe acesse seus membros desta maneira, tente mudar para private, e forneça um método de acesso, assim você pode encapsular e proteger seus dados.

Answer (score 0):

Seria bom você criar um *identificador único* para seu contato, exemplo:

```
public class Contato {
    private int id; /* aqui */
    private String nome;
    private String email;
    private int telefone;

    /*getters e setter*/
}
```

---

E na sua Agenda criar seu gerenciador para ter um **auto incremento** a cada novo contato.

```
public class Agenda implements Interface {
    public static ArrayList<Contato> contatos = new ArrayList<Contato>();
    private static int incrementoContato = 1;
    // metodos
}
```

E na hora de **adicionar**

```
@Override
public void adicionar(Contato contato) {
    if (contato == null) return;
    contato.setId(this.incrementoContato++); //vai gerar id 1, 2, 3...
    this.contatos.add(contato);     
}
```

---

E na sua **busca** vai de você escolher se vai querer procurar por algum campo e você precisa trocar o retorno dele de `void` para `Contato`. Exemplo:

```
@Override
public Contato buscar(String nome, String email) {
     boolean naoFiltrarNome = (nome == null || nome.trim().isEmpty());
     boolean naoFiltrarEmail = (email == null || email.trim().isEmpty());

     for (Contato c : contatos) {
          if ((c.getNome().contains(nome.trim()) || naoFiltrarNome) &&
              (c.getEmail().contains(email.trim()) || naoFiltrarEmail)) {
               return c;
          }
     }
     return null; // não encontrou
}
```

Esses booleanos `naoFiltrarNome` e `naoFiltrarEmail` serve pra você saber se deve filtrar por eles ou não, exemplo:

- Quero filtrar **APENAS POR NOME**: buscar("Maicon", null);
- Quero filtrar **APENAS POR EMAIL**: buscar(null, "maicon@email.com");
- Se quiser pelos dois, só passar os dois. E o `contains` no `if` permite que seja apenas contendo uma palavra, se o contato tem o nome *"Maicon Carraro"* posso passar só *"Maicon"*.
- Se o retorno for nulo, então não encontrou.
- Se quiser retornar uma lista é só adaptar o tipo do retorno e ir adicionando numa lista auxiliar.

---

Sobre seu **editar** é aqui que vamos usar o identificador.

```
@Override
public void editar(Contato contato) {
    if (contato == null) null;
    boolean encontrou = false;

    for (Contato c : contatos) {
         if (c.getId() == contato.getId()) {
              // mesmo identificador, então atualiza os valores
              c.setNome(contato.getNome());
              c.setEmail(contato.getEmail());
              c.setTelefone(contato.getTelefone());

              encontrou = true;
              break;
         }
    }

    // Caso não encontrar pra atualizar, adiciona na lista como um novo (opcional)
    if (!encontrou) {
         adicionar(contato);
    }
}
```

---

Acredito que isso vai te dar uma luz de como fazer as coisas :)